# PyGitHub: Get Total number of commits for a repository

Tags: python, git, github-api, pygithub

I am trying to get total number of Commits for each repository for repositories using Python GitHub.

Code:

```
 from github import Github
 git = Github("token")
 org = git.get_organization('organization')

 for repo in org.get_repos():
        repository_commit_date = repo.get_commit(sha='master')
        stats_ = repository_commit_date.stats
        print(stats_.total)
```

The code returns something else and it doesn't match the actual number of commits for the repositories. Can someone help me with this?

I want the output to look like:

Output:

```
 Repository Name: hello-world
 Number of commits: 62
```

Comment: what does this program return? what is the expected output?

Comment: What do you compare your results with? `git rev-list --count HEAD`?

Comment: @Nagashayan. Thanks for asking the clarification. Please see the edited question. Hope it helps

Comment: @RomainValeri. Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some googling I was able to get total number of commits for a GitHub repository.

```
from github import Github
g = Github("username","password")
for repo in g.get_user().get_repos():
    print(repo.name, repo.get_commits().totalCount)
```

For more information search here: https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub